# Youtube iframe API with AJAX and autoplay/queuing

Tags: iframe, youtube-api

I'm using the Youtube iframe API, and I'm trying to get autoplay and queuing, polling, and start/stop working.

I'm starting with just getting autoplay to work. I've looked at the developer documentation so please don't post another link to that.

I include the API:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

but because this is an AJAX request, and the DIV which holds the player isn't in the DOM when the page is loaded, I don't call `function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()`

Instead, when the player is to be loaded (which is always long after the DOM has been loaded), I call

```
var videoID = video.split('=').pop();

var player = new YT.Player('video_holder', {
             width:  "480", 
             height: "295", 
             videoId: videoID,
             events: {'onready': onPlayerReady}
             });
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

This code loads the video, but the video doesn't play. The only error I have in the console is the `unsafe JavaScript attempt to access` error, which I understand is common for the iframe API.

Answer (score -1):

The event names are case sensitive so change `onready` to `onReady`.